# (PYTHON) while statement help 2.7

Tags: python, while-loop

I've mostly been using Python 3.2 but moving on to 2.7 just for visual base purposes. I can't seem to make my loop form an endless cycle, say if the user enters the incorrect phrase, the code just breaks after inputting the wrong variable.

```
 measure = raw_input("what form of measurement do you want to use: 
 (enter CM or IN): ")
 while True:
     if measure == str('cm'):
         break
     elif measure == str("in"):
         break
     else:
         measure =  input("please enter cm or in")
         continue
```

Comment: can you fix your indentations?

Comment: What's a "visual base purpose"?

Comment: @Kevin i have to use python to draw a 3d shape

Comment: Is Python 3.2 any worse at drawing 3d shapes than Python 2.7?

Comment: use `raw_input` in your `else` statement

Comment: `str('cm')` is duplicative... `'cm'` is already a string. You prompt for upper case but only check lower case. And when you go into the `else`, you switch to `input` instead of `raw_input`. Python does an `eval` on the string so typing in `'cm'` would raise a variable-not-found error.

Comment: @Kevin no... just wont install on my computer and i really dont want to spend time finding out why

Comment: thanks i fixed it haha, raw_input i forgot

Comment: _the code just breaks_ - this type of error has a stack trace. Please post that so that we can narrow "breaks" down to its root cause.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried it you were throwing an error by trying to use input over `raw_input` in your `else` block. Try the below:

```
measure = raw_input("what form of measurement do you want to use: 
 (enter CM or IN): ")
 while True:
     if measure == str('cm'):
         break
     elif measure == str("in"):
         break
     else:
         measure =  input("please enter cm or in")
         continue
```

Even better, to avoid using `break` or `continue`, you can use the below, which simplifies your logic and takes upper and lower case into account:

```
measure = raw_input("what form of measurement do you want to use: (enter CM or IN): ").lower()

while measure != 'cm' and measure != 'in':
    measure = raw_input("please enter cm or in").lower()
```

Comment: You don't deal with upper/lower case

Comment: Fixed to deal with cases!

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a mashup of the code in the comments that was tested to work

```
 measure = raw_input("what form of measurement do you want to use: (enter CM or IN): ")
 while True:
     if measure == 'cm':
         break
     elif measure == "in":
         break
     else:
         measure =  raw_input("please enter cm or in: ")
         continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
measure = raw_input("what form of measurement do you want to use:  (enter CM or IN): ")
b = True
while b:
     if measure == 'cm' or measure == "in":
         b = False
     else:
         measure = raw_input("please enter cm or in ")
```

Just change your last `input` to `raw_input`

Comment: `str('cm')` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

What about indentation? Don't forget that indentation is the way python knows if you are still in the while/if/for/... statement.
I don't have a python interpreter right here but my guess is that it should work if you indent it right. Moreover, it would be much better to use another condition like `while measure != "cm" and measure != "in"`

```
measure = raw_input("blablabla")
while measure != "cm" and measure != "in":
  measure =  raw_input("please enter cm or in: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rework your code so that you have a single prompt for data. Remove unneeded `str` conversions, test using upper case, and just check if the entered value is in a list of wanted values. (and get rid of that syntax error you get by putting the string on multiple lines)

```
while True:
    measure = raw_input("what form of measurement do you want to use:"
    " (enter CM or IN): ").strip()
    if measure.upper() in ("CM", "IN"):
        break
    print("Incorrect input, try again")
```